# Spark test with scalaTest unsuccessful

Tags: scala

Here is a Test class for a Spark application in scala using ScalaTest, when running **sbt test** I get a  **java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError** caused by **org.apache.spark.SparkException: A master URL must be set in your configuration** and the test is not executed, which I don't understand since I'm setting the master to local when declaring conf. Does anyone have an idea why ?

**The Test Class:**

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.scalatest._

class SizeByMailboxTest extends FlatSpec with Matchers with BeforeAndAfter {

   val master = "local"
   val appName = "example-spark"
   var sc: SparkContext = _

  before {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster(master).setAppName(appName)
    sc = new SparkContext(conf)
  }

  after {
    if (sc != null) {
      sc.stop()
    }
}
  behavior of "SizeByMailbox"
  it should "count total content size per mailbox  with duplicates" in { 
    val sample = Array(
                       SizeByMailbox.Message("1",10,50),
                       SizeByMailbox.Message("2",5,60),
                       SizeByMailbox.Message("2",8,40),
                       SizeByMailbox.Message("1",7,80)
                      ) 
    val samples = sc.parallelize(sample)
    val sizeById = SizeByMailbox.count(samples)
    sizeById.collect().map(m=>SizeByMailbox.MailBox(m.mailboxid,m.totalsize)) should contain allOf (SizeByMailbox.MailBox("1", 130),SizeByMailbox.MailBox("2", 100))
  }       
}
```

The App:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import com.datastax.spark.connector._
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD


object SizeByMailbox {
   val sc = new SparkContext();
   case class Message(mailboxid: String, bodyoctets: Int,fullcontentoctets: Int) ;
   case class MailBox(mailboxid: String,totalsize: Int); 
   def count(messages: RDD[Message]) : RDD[MailBox] = {

      val total_by_mailbox = messages.map (m =>     (m.mailboxid,m.fullcontentoctets)).reduceByKey(_+_).map( m => MailBox(m._1,m._2))
      total_by_mailbox
   }
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
       `**enter code here**` ....
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating another `SparkContext` in the App itself which does not have the `SparkConf` specified and as a result has no master URL.

```
object SizeByMailbox {
    val sc = new SparkContext(); <-- here
```

You have not posted the stacktrace but that is what I suspect the error to be.

As a good practice try not to create more than one *active* SparkContext in a JVM as Spark can behave unpredictably.